# Loop through inner nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

This is my object:

```
family_Data = {
    "Family": [
        {
            "id": "Family-15",
            "members":
            {
                "Family-15-01": [{"Family Code": "Family-15-01","Gender": "Female", "Full Name" : "Evelyn Osei"}],
                "Family-15-02": [{"Family Code": "Family-15-02","Gender": "Male", "Full Name" : "David Will"}],
                "Family-15-03": [{"Family Code": "Family-15-03","Gender": "Male", "Full Name" : "Edwin Pan"}]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to loop through the "members" objects.

Comment: Trivial using nested `$.each`, but what have you tried?

Comment: HINT: `family_Data.Family[0].members` refers to the object you want to loop through.

Comment: You can use `for(var key in family_Data.Family[0].members)` to loop through object getting all keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var family_Data = {
"Family": [
{
"id": "Family-15",
"members": {
"Family-15-01": [{"Family Code": "Family-15-01","Gender": "Female", "Full Name" : "Evelyn Osei"}],
"Family-15-02": [{"Family Code": "Family-15-02","Gender": "Male", "Full Name" : "David Will"}],
"Family-15-03": [{"Family Code": "Family-15-03","Gender": "Male", "Full Name" : "Edwin Pan"}]
}
}
]
};
for(var key in family_Data.Family[0].members){
  console.log(family_Data.Family[0].members[key]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get your `members` object.

```
var members = family_Data.Family[0].members;
```

then iterate over the object.

```
for(var key in members){
   var member = members[key];
   // here we go.
}
```

Comment: Subash, your code works fine  but can you help me remove the Family code please.  I want the objects  like this :  "members": {
[{"Family Code": "Family-15-01","Gender": "Female", "Full Name" : "Evelyn Osei"}],
[{"Family Code": "Family-15-02","Gender": "Male", "Full Name" : "David Will"}],
 [{"Family Code": "Family-15-03","Gender": "Male", "Full Name" : "Edwin Pan"}]
}

Comment: I have sorted myself out Subash. This is what i did.   var result = {};
                    member.forEach(x => {
                        result[x.que] = x.ans;
                    });